# Tableau compute the diff between first and last column of the current table view

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-columns

I need to do a task similar to the following scenario. Let's say I have a file of 10 products' sales from 2000 to 2014, and our internal product rank of importance (from 1-10). So the data file has 4 variables, product name, internal rank, sales, year, e.g., for product1:

1. product1, 5, 1000, 2000
2. product1, 5, 2000, 2001
3. product1, 5, 3000, 2002
4. ...

Some products have sales data missing for the first few years.

The table I have now on Tableau worksheet displays each product in a row, followed by the internal rank, each year's sales from 2000 to 2014, and the 15 year average per row/product. e.g., for product1:

1. product1, 5, 1000, 2000, 3000, (2003sales...2014sales), average sale 2000-2014

I want to add another column that shows the difference between the first available sales year and 2014, e.g., product1 has complete data, so this column would be sales difference between 2014 and 2000. product2 sales started in 2002, so this column would be difference between 2014 and 2002.

I guess some LOD codes may do the trick? Could anyone please help? The standard table calculation isn't helpful, or maybe I haven't figured it out. Thanks so much!

Comment: Is the first layout the data source and the second one how you layed it out in the worksheet?

Comment: yes, the second one is the table I am creating on worksheet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

1. create 4 calculated fields `[2000]`, `[2001]`, `[2013]` and `[2014]` with the formula:

   ```
   IF [year] = 2000 THEN 
   [sales] 
   END
   ```

   for each field you replace the year with 2013 or 2014
2. create another 4 calculated fields `[Sales2000]`, `[Sales2001]`, `[Sales2013]` and `[Sales2014]`:

   ```
   {fixed ProductName: sum([Sales2000])}
   ```

   again change the year accordingly
3. create the calculated fields for the difference `[diff2000-2014]` and `[diff2013-2014]`:

   ```
   IF Isnull([Sales2000]) THEN 
   [Sales2014] - [Sales2001] 
   ELSE 
   [Sales2014] - [Sales2000] 
   END
   ```

   and

   ```
   [Sales2014] - [Sales2013]
   ```

So what you did was

1. You extract the values for the years you need
2. You assign them to all rows with the product
3. you calculated the difference you wanted
4. If you want it in the worksheet now, drag the `[diff2013-2014]` field inton the columsn shelf and select MIN(), MAX() or AVG() since you don't want to add up all the differences.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for the codes. Could you please explain the does for creating sales2000 etc. The fieldname to be created is in the code itself?

Comment: Also, for some products, year 2000 data are missing, so I need to use year 2001 sales instead. So the added column is actually the diff between 2014 and whichever starting year is available. Sorry I wasn't clear at first.

Comment: @May I adjusted the answer. It becomes a bit messy but it should do the job.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was able to do the calculation correctly. But adding the new field to the original table (with every year sales) didn't work. I explored two options, 1) creating two new tables one for diff 2014-2013 and one for diff 2014-starting year, and then put all three tables on a dashboard side by side, aligning all to fill the entire review.

Comment: and 2) export the original table from Tableau to excel, and do the calculation there. I ended up using this option, because it is faster. Adding sparklines also seem faster in excel than Tableau.